# Access JSON Array through Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have some JSON Data like this:

```
[{"2015-02-10": ["00:00","00:30","01:00","01:30","02:00","02:30","03:00","03:30","04:00","04:30","05:00","05:30","06:00","06:30","07:00","07:30","12-00","12-30","13-00","13-30","18:00","18:30","19:00","19:30","20:00","20:30","21:00","21:30","22:00","22:30","23:00","23:30"]},{"2015-02-17": ["00:00","00:30","01:00","01:30","02:00","02:30","03:00","03:30","04:00","04:30","05:00","05:30","06:00","06:30","07:00","07:30","12-00","12-30","13-00","13-30","18:00","18:30","19:00","19:30","20:00","20:30","21:00","21:30","22:00","22:30","23:00","23:30"]}]
```

Now I parse it in Javascript and tried to access the values of a specific date:

```
var hours = $.parseJSON('JSON STRING ...');
var date = "2015-02-10";
console.log(hours[date]);
```

But I always get "undefined" and I really don't know how I can access this

Comment: The "JSON Data" you have is actually an Array, containing an object, containing an array. `hours[0][date]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is an array (`[ ... ]`) with an object inside it.

Try:

```
console.log(hours[0][date]);
```

Comment: Thanks i tried it before but as date is an dynamic value I don't know which index it has.
So i changed the JSON structure to this:

`{"2015-02-10": ["00:00","00:30","01:00","01:30","02:00","02:30","03:00","03:30","04:00","04:30","05:00","05:30"],"2015-02-17": ["00:00","00:30"]}`

So i can access directly via key :)